# How to parse Sphinx custom directive content to docutil nodes

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I'm trying to create a custom directive called `LicenceDirective` which looks like it:

```
.. licence: Some Software 3.0
   :url: https://SomeSoftware.com/downloads
   :path: /licence_file

   CONTENT
```

The HTML output of such directive would be:

```html
<h1 id="some-software-3-0">Some Software 3.0</h1>
<p><a href="https://SomeSoftware.com/downloads">Download page</a></p>
RST_PARSED(CONTENT)
<pre>{{content of licence_file}}</pre>
```

`CONTENT` can be any valid RST content, including formatting, lists, headers, ... .
So i need to parse it as-is and return the resulting nodes to return them along with my own nodes from `LicenceDirective::run()`.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Start here: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_directive Update your answer with what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution using `nested_parse`, and mentioned here:

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/markupapi.html#parsing-directive-content-as-rest